# Some ways to combine sets in python

Tags: python, function, set

I am trying to write a game that uses grids, and I need a way to make sets by combining two other sets.

For example, if I had `[a, b, c]` and `[1, 2, 3]`, are there are any functions in Python 3 that will give me `[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [41]: import itertools

In [42]: x='abc'

In [43]: y='123'

In [45]: [letter+num for letter,num in itertools.product(x,y)]
Out[45]: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

Comment: Note that product doesn't care what type of iterable x and y are. `x='abc'` works just as well as `x=['a','b','c']` etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Take a look at the map function.

Comment: Python has explicit product functions (for lists and also as part of itertools). I don't think map is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
numbers = [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ]

[x + str(y) for x in letters for y in numbers]
```